# 'Type non-static const member can't use default assignment operator' - what does this mean?

Tags: c++, constants

This class is flagging up the following error:
'non-static const member 'const int Member::membershipNo', can't use default assignment operator'. The strange thing is this code is repeated in another project and works perfectly. Can you help me put it right?

Member.h

```
class Member : public Person
    {
    public:
        Member();
        Member(int membershipNo);
        virtual ~Member();

        int getMembershipNo() const;

    private:
        const int membershipNo;

        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Person>(*this);
            ar & membershipNo;
        }

    };
```

Member.cpp

```
Member::Member() : membershipNo(0)
{
    Person();
}

Member::Member(int memberNo) : membershipNo(memberNo)
{
    Person();
}

Member::~Member()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

int Member::getMembershipNo() const
{
    return membershipNo;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably, somewhere in your code you are assigning to a `Member`, something like this:

```
Member m1, m2;
m1 = m2;
```

Or you are using it in a context that requires the type to be assignable.

Since you don't provide your own assignment operator overload for `Member`, the implicitly defined defaulted assignment operator would usually kick in. However, since you have a `const` data member, the compiler won't implicitly define one for you. You *need* to provide it yourself.

This makes sense because, imagine in the code sample I just gave, what should the compiler do to `m1`'s `membershipNo` member? Should it assign `m2`'s `membershipNo` to it? How can it do that if `membershipNo` is `const`? In this case, the compiler just says "Nope, I can't do it."

> A defaulted copy/move assignment operator for class `X` is defined as deleted if `X` has:
>
> - a non-static data member of `const` non-class type (or array thereof)
> - [...]

As I said, to be able to do assignment with a `Member`, you need to provide an assignment operator of your own:

```
Member& Member::operator=(const Member& other)
{
  // Copy things from other to this
}
```

However, herein lies the problem with having `const` members. If you supply your own copy assignment operator as described, and you *don't* copy over `membershipNo`, then have you really copied the other object? Logically, it makes sense that an object that has any `const` state *shouldn't* be able to be assigned to.

It is perfectly fine to use a copy constructor however - you only have to make sure you initialise `membershipNo` in the member initialization list:

```
Member::Member(const Member& other)
  : membershipNo(other.membershipNo)
{
  // ...
}
```

And then you can do:

```
Member m1;
Member m2 = m1;
```

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. So is there no way to copy using a copy constructor an object that has const data?

Comment: @Frammo Copy constructor is perfectly fine. Copy assignment is not - unless you provide your own.

Comment: Sorry. Got mixed up with the copy constructor and assignment operator overload method. I gave you accepted answer as it was slightly more in depth than the first.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening is that some client code is attempting to use assign one `Member` instance to another one. Since you have a constant data member, this cannot work. The error will only come up if some code attempts to make the assignment, which is why it may seem the same class "works" in another project.

In terms of putting it right, the options are A) not to perform the assignment, or B) make the data member non-const.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. Thank you. So it there no way to copy/assign an instance that has const members? Why would making a copy break the rules of changing the value of the const data?

Comment: @Frammo copying is OK. Assigning is not. When you assign LHS = RHS, LHS has already been initialized and the assignment implies a change in its state. And if the state is const...